# Download, unzip, and load Excel file in R using tempfiles only

Tags: r, excel, download, unzip, temp

I am trying and failing to write a process that will download a .zip archive, extract a particular Excel file from that archive, and load that Excel file into my R workspace without ever writing any of those files (the .zip or the .xls) to my hard drive.

I have written a version of this process that works for zipped .csvs, but it doesn't work for .xls. Here's how that version goes, using one of the URLs I'm targeting in my current project and using `readWorksheetFromFile()` instead of `read.csv()` at the appropriate moment:

```
library(XLConnect)
waed.old.link <- "http://eventdata.parusanalytics.com/data.dir/pitf.world.19950101-20121231.xls.zip"
waed.old.file <- "pitf.world.19950101-20121231.xls"
tmp <- tempfile()
download.file(waed.old.link, tmp)
tmp2 <- tempfile()
tmp2 <- unz(tmp, waed.old.file)
WAED.old <- readWorksheetFromFile(tmp2, sheet = 1, startRow = 3, startCol = 1, endCol = 73)
unlink(tmp)
unlink(tmp2)
```

And here's what pops up after line 8, the one that tries to ingest the spreadsheet as `WAED.old`:

```
Error in path.expand(filename) : invalid 'path' argument
```

I also tried `read_excel()` at that step and got the same result:

```
> WAED.old <- read_excel(tmp2, skip = 2)
Error in file.exists(path) : invalid 'file' argument
```

I gather that this has something to do with pointing `readWorksheetFromFile()` at a connection rather than a file, but I'm not sure that's right, and I don't know how to fix it if it is. I searched stackoverflow and the web for an answer but couldn't find one that was right on point. I'd really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you say, it is because `unz` returns a connection object for the file within the zip (but does not explicitly unzip that file), while `readWorksheetFromFile` expects a path to a file.

Use `unzip` to explicitly unzip the file.

```
tmp2 <- unzip(zipfile=tmp, files = waed.old.file, exdir=tempdir())
# readWorksheetFromFile(tmp2, ...)
```